# Why is my submit button not submitting form data? - HTML/Node

Tags: html

I've got a simple form which I'm wanting people to join to be put onto a waiting list for my product - but it's not submitting.

My application is being hosted on localhost:3000 and runs absolutely fine. The page renders and you can fill the inputs in.

But when you click 'submit' it does nothing. I've tried doing a few different 'types' of the button, but no luck.

Here's my code:

```
<section class="waiting-list-section">
  <div class="waiting-container">
    <div class="waiting-heading">
      <h2>Join our waiting list</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="waiting-inputs">
      <label for="fName">Enter your first name</label>
      <input type="text" name="fName" value="">
      <label for="lName">Enter your surname</label>
      <input type="text" name="lName" value="">
      <label for="email">Enter your email</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" value="">
      <button class="waiting-submit-button glow" type="submit" name="submit">Join</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Any tips? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `form` element wrapped around the input elements and the button.

```html
<form>
  <label for="fName">Enter your first name</label>
  <input type="text" name="fName" value="">
  <label for="lName">Enter your surname</label>
  <input type="text" name="lName" value="">
  <label for="email">Enter your email</label>
  <input type="email" name="email" value="">
  <button class="waiting-submit-button glow" type="submit" name="submit">Join</button>
</form>
```

Second approach would be to add an eventListener on the button and when it is clicked, get the values from the inputs and then do whatever you want to do with that data

Comment: Doh! That was obvious! Thank you.